# how to call / check data of only one row of mysql database in a session array using php?

Tags: php, mysql

say, there are two database tables named

`user`

```
id    name
--   -----
1     Mike
2     Bob
3     Tony
4     Christina
5     James
```

`product`

```
product_id    chooser_id   chooser_name   selection_status
----------    ----------   ------------   -----------------
   1               1             Mike              0
   2               2             Bob               1
   3               3             Tony              0
   4               3             Tony              1
   5               3             Tony              1
```

here data available in the above `product` table are inserted by the logged in users of `user` table based on the following mysql syntax.

```
mysql_select_db($database_XYZ, $XYZ);
$query_test = "SELECT user.id, user.name, product.product_id, product.chooser_id, product.chooser_name, product.selection_status FROM user, product WHERE user.id = '$_SESSION[userid]' AND user.id = product.chooser_id AND product.selection_status = 1 ";
$test = mysql_query($query_$test, $XYZ) or die(mysql_error());
$row_test  = mysql_fetch_assoc($test );
$totalRows_test  = mysql_num_rows($test );
```

now if the user **Tony** wants to check the `selection_status` (`0` & `1` are flagged values) of `product` table inserted by him in a logged in session depending on the following syntax

```
if (isset($row_test ["selection_status"]) == "1") {
echo $row_test ["selection_status"];
}
```

the syntax unusually returns `1`, `1` as he is still logged in while checking the data and it fetches all rows which unexpectedly seem to match `mysql` query from following part of `product` table :

```
product_id    chooser_id   chooser_name   selection_status
----------   -----------   -------------  -----------------
   4               3             Tony              1
   5               3             Tony              1
```

how to call / check only one row of mysql database in a session array using alternative php conditional statement so that it returns the data of only one row in each check or call like?

```
product_id    chooser_id   chooser_name   selection_status
----------   -----------   -------------  -----------------
   4               3             Tony              1
```

or

```
product_id    chooser_id   chooser_name   selection_status
----------   -----------   -------------  -----------------
   5               3             Tony              1
```

please note that, `mysql LIMIT` and `WHERE product_id=4` etc. won't be applicable here since data shall be populated here through session.

Comment: Why are you testing `isset($row_test ["selection_status"])`? `mysql_fetch_assoc()` will always set that.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Do you just want to know if there are any rows where `selection_status = 1`? Then just check if `$totalRows_test > 0`?

Comment: Why won't it be user specific? The query has `WHERE user.id = '$_SESSION[userid]'`.

Comment: Why doesn't `LIMIT 1` do what you want? I don't understand the last line of the question about it not being applicable.

Comment: The WHERE clause chooses the data that's selected, and then LIMIT 1 picks 1 row from that result set.

Comment: [Please, don't use mysql_* functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) in new code. They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [_prepared statements_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which.

Comment: the user specific data should be both `product_id` & `selection_status` specific single row data. the syntax shouldn't fetch data from `product_id=4` when data of `product_id=5` are being populated on page. does LIMIT 1 serve that purpose? doesn't LIMIT 1 fetch the first 1 element like, `product_id=4` of the array unless `MYSQL` syntax is defined with `ORDER BY product.product_id DESC`? the possible syntax should filter only one row base on both `product_id` & `selection_status` even there are 1000 of `selection_status`  matches there. `product_id` data are identical here.

Answer (score 0):

the problem has been solved. in if (isset($row_test ["selection_status"]) == "1"){ . isset was returning true or not null over available data. so i removed it and changed the syntax to if ($row_test ["selection_status"] == "1"){ . moreover i erase the condition `AND product.selection_status = 1` from mysql syntax.

**lesson to learn from this post:** `flagged value` as condition in session based complex `mysql` query for filtering unique/primary id specific row can't maintain the rule of `session variable`. this is an exceptional case which doesn't follow `session rule`. in this case flagged value should be called using php conditional or comparison statement when necessary other than mysql query.